# Long tap on tabs issue

Tags: bug, ios-app

Long tap on tabs doesn't drop previous selection. E.g.:

1. Select SO site
2. Long tap on child tabs (successively)

   > [image: all selected]

I didn't know about ability of long tap on tabs in the iOS app until today.

---

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)